# How to return as multiple columns instead of an array of matched regexp_matches results in psql?

Tags: postgresql

Currently I have to manually extract nth paranthesized subexpression matches, and duplicate regex for the number of parantheses,

```
SELECT regexp_matches(col2, '(\d)(\d)(\d)')[1], 
       regexp_matches(col2, '(\d)(\d)(\d)')[2],
       regexp_matches(col2, '(\d)(\d)(\d)')[3]
FROM tab;
```

I guess the manual way is highly inefficient.

Is there a way to auto decompose the result array into multiple columns? and return null if the n'th parenthesized subexpression of the pattern doesn't match?

Comment: What exactly is your expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
select res[1] val1, res[2] val2
from (SELECT regexp_matches(col2, '(bar)(beque)') res FROM tab) y;

 val1 | val2  
------+-------
 bar  | beque
```

Splitting into tabular format:

```
select unnest(res) as tabular
from (SELECT regexp_matches(col2, '(bar)(beque)') res FROM tab) y;

 tabular 
--------
 bar
 beque
```

Comment: Yes, like this. Is this the most common way of handling it?

Comment: I guess "common" is a product of what you need to do. This is typical way of splitting the results from the `regexp_matches` function, but you can also split it out into tabular format. I'll update my example with that.

Comment: @bma Do you happen to know what is an alternative solution for `regexp_matches`? I'm using redshift database, so I can only use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, `REGEXP_COUNT`, and `REGEXP_INSTR` function.